# How can I split a DataFrame by column index without knowing the precise index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database of stock prices with the DateTime index of the trading days from 31dec2001 till 31dec2021. I have to divide the database in 6-months periods, e.g from 01 Jan 2001 to 30 Jun 2001 and so on. My idea was to use the following:

```
period_1 = df.loc["20010101": "20010530", :]
```

and it works, but when I try this:

```
period_2 = df.loc["20010601":"20013112", :]
```

it doesn't work. That's because those indexes don't exist (these are weekend days), so the correct way to proceed would be to select the immediately previous trading day. How could I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect your index dtype is Object and not datetime.

Comment: +1, there is no reason why it should not work (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68529251/16343464)). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to reproduce the issue. @ldr actually if the index is string and one uses string slices, it should work… might be int?

Answer (score 1):

`df.index.get_loc()` function returns integer location, slice or boolean mask for requested label. The function works with both sorted as well as unsorted Indexes. It provides various options if the passed value is not present in the Index.

Try `df.index.get_loc(your_datetime, method='nearest'))`

Answer (score 0):

It is unexpected. The indexes need not to exist for slicing. Please, give an extract of you dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': list('ABCD')},
                  index=['202107%02d' % i for i in range(1,8,2)])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

```
           value
2021-07-01     A
2021-07-03     B
2021-07-05     C
2021-07-07     D
```

```
>>> df.loc[:'20210706']
           value
2021-07-01     A
2021-07-03     B
2021-07-05     C

>>> df.loc['20210702':'20210706', :]
           value
2021-07-03     B
2021-07-05     C
```

Here is how to get it to work with your dataset:

```
df = pd.read_csv('adj_close_ok.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv('adj_close_ok.csv', index_col=[0])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

output:

```
              A2A.MI  AMP.MI  ATL.MI  AZM.MI  BGN.MI    BMED.MI    BPE.MI    BZU.MI  CPR.MI  DIA.MI   ENEL.MI    ENI.MI     EXO.MI       G.MI  HER.MI     IP.MI    ISP.MI  LDO.MI     MB.MI  PRY.MI     REC.MI     SPM.MI  SRG.MI   STLA.MI     STM.MI  TEN.MI    TIT.MI  TRN.MI       UCG.MI      UNI.MI
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2001-01-01       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN  4.009817       NaN     NaN     NaN  1.749866  4.356510  22.522886        NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN -29.186302        NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN  2.041652     NaN -4447.237305 -945.632324
2001-01-02  1.317167     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN -70.362572  4.066304  6.569647     NaN     NaN  1.725220  4.335370  22.650860  19.351480     NaN  2.421396  1.828341     NaN  6.393895     NaN -29.738869 -89.672943     NaN  3.149144  23.250896     NaN  2.019121     NaN -3734.218994 -937.409363
2001-01-03  1.266015     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN -64.066391  4.122792  6.747204     NaN     NaN  1.730149  4.375732  21.243177  19.152739     NaN  2.368707  1.796041     NaN  6.337817     NaN -28.548735 -91.766136     NaN  3.130977  21.422487     NaN  2.005255     NaN -3720.711426 -937.409363
2001-01-04  1.283065     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN -68.208611  4.179247  6.917660     NaN     NaN  1.774512  4.297570  22.011002  18.764509     NaN  2.396468  1.814853     NaN  6.392828     NaN -28.449564 -89.536446     NaN  3.098274  24.806408     NaN  2.076315     NaN -3808.496582 -942.891357
2001-01-05  1.231913     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN -72.074692  4.190564  7.066810     NaN     NaN  1.730149  4.264256  22.394915  18.172918     NaN  2.319419  1.857092     NaN  6.345294     NaN -28.761259 -87.974159     NaN  3.146722  24.015007     NaN  2.126576     NaN -3909.786865 -942.891357
...
```

### split by semesters

Also, if you want to index by quarter/semester you can do:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'value': list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')},
                       index=['2021%02d01' % (i+1) for i in range(12)])
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
>>> df
           value
2021-01-01     A
2021-02-01     B
2021-03-01     C
2021-04-01     D
2021-05-01     E
2021-06-01     F
2021-07-01     G
2021-08-01     H
2021-09-01     I
2021-10-01     J
2021-11-01     K
2021-12-01     L

>>> df_semester1 = df[df.index.quarter<3]
>>> df_semester1
           value
2021-01-01     A
2021-02-01     B
2021-03-01     C
2021-04-01     D
2021-05-01     E
2021-06-01     F
```

Comment: Here the database https://www.dropbox.com/s/3eyvjh93dasa48m/adj_close_ok.csv?dl=0

Comment: The community prefers not having to download data from unknown links. Instead you should follow this guide to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I imagine that you did not have Date as index, but rather a column. I updated my answer to show you how to load your dataset. Slicing is working fine

Comment: Thank you @mozway , you figured out the problem. Now it works fine!!